# Setting an environment variable that launches Octave

Tags: bash, macos, octave

I recently installed octave on macOS and I can launch octave fine by running Octave-cli in Applications or by running in terminal `/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/octave-3.8.0`.

How can I set it so octave-cli runs in terminal when I type `octave`?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `PATH` variable to include the octave install location (folder). You can do this by editing your `.bash_profile` file in your **home directory**. Append the following to the file (create it if it doesn't exist) and start a new terminal session.

```
export PATH="$PATH:<path to your octave install directory>"
```

If want to test it in your current terminal session just run the command above. All putting it the profile does is ensure it is run every time you start a new terminal window.

Also, my install directory seems to be a bit different from yours so you may want to double check you installed it correctly. The octave executables are located in `/usr/local/bin` for me. This is already in my `PATH` so I didn't need to update my bash profile.

Comment: I added it into bash profile and saved but still getting octave command not found

Comment: Either type "source .bash_profile" or restart your terminal.

Comment: Also, make sure the path is correct. I have octave installed and its at a different path.

Comment: Still not working after all that. I used the location that it is at when I open octave-cli and did source .bash_profile

Comment: Well the answer is correct - I have to do this all the time for other software. If you want to run a command from the terminal it has to be able to find it in the path variable. If you are new to appending to your path maybe do a couple quick searches on that. Perhaps the file is in the wrong place or something is misspelled. Good luck.

Comment: Got it. I had to open it with octave-3.8.0 rather than octave. Any way to change that?

Comment: Rename the executable "octave-3.8.0" -> "octave". Or create a symlink (just look that up).